# How to instantiate an Object in a class which extends HttpServlet?

Tags: java, http, session, servlets

I have a class which extends the HttpServlet class. I know that Java it's multithreaded and different threads (read: HTTP requests) can make use of the same instance. I want to instantiate an Object on the first request and use it until the end of session.

How should I proceed?

For example : I want to open a file on the first request and close it at the end of session.

Comment: When you say session, do you mean a user's http session visiting your site or do you mean a single request to the servlet?

Comment: when I say session I mean a user's http session visiting my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either just instantiate it yourself in one of the servlet's `doXxx()` methods depending on its presence in the session

```
SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject) request.getSession().getAttribute("someObject");

if (someObject == null) {
    someObject = new SomeObject();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("someObject", someObject);
}

// Use someObject.
```

Or you could instantiate it yourself in a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)

```
@WebListener
public class SomeObjectInitializer implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setAttribute("someObject", new SomeObject());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

}
```

Either way, the `SomeObject` itself could implement [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) so that you can perform some logic during binding and unbinding to the session.

```
public class SomeObject implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        // Perform job during adding to the session.
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        // Perform job during removal from the session.
    }

}
```

Comment: Balusc I tried to instantiate it in my doGet() method but it seems that even I save the Object with request.getSession().setAttribute("x",x) method, when I try to get it, the object is always NULL

Comment: Then either the session is not maintained properly (use the webbrowser's developer toolset to track `JSESSIONID` cookie), or you used the wrong attribute name (case sensitive!), or you actually have put `null` in it.

Comment: I checked and it seems that the session is not maintained properly. Do you know how can I keep the session alive? I tried "request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60)" but it doesn't worked

Comment: You need to ensure that your webbrowser has cookies enabled and that you aren't calling session.invalidate() anywhere. The setMaxInactiveInterval() should not be necessary. It defaults to 30 seconds already.

Comment: My webbrowser has cookies enabled. I checked the source code and I don't call the invalidate() method. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Okay. How exactly did you conclude that the session is not maintained properly? Did the `JSESSIONID` cookie change on every response? Or did the client not send it along with every request?

Comment: well,the JSESSIONID cookie changes by every response.

Comment: Okay, does the client send the `JSESSIONID` cookie from last response along with every next request or not? If it does, then the problem is definitely in server side (e.g. `session.invalidate()` **is** been invoked). If it does not, then the problem is definitely in client side (e.g. cookies **are** disabled).

Comment: I checked and the client send the JSESSIONID cookie from last request along with the response of that request. After that the request JSESSIONID cookie changes. I am not sure if I proceeded properly : I printout the request.getSession.getId() and I compared it with the JSESSIONID cookie value from the response (captured with Firebug)

Comment: For starters, it'd be easier to implement a `HttpSessionListener` and put a breakpoint in `sessionCreated()` and `sessionDestroyed()` methods so that you can track down in the stack to figure when and why exactly the session has been created and destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to instantiate an Object on the first request and use it until the end of session.

Well, that suggests you should put it in the session, not in the servlet.

See [this tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html) for some details around using sessions from Java servlets. Note that if you want to scale out to multiple servers, you'll need to think carefully about how that affects sessoins. (You could persist the session information in a database, or attempt to configure your load balancer to send all requests for the same session to the same machine, etc.)